# Adding custom drodpdown on column Header in ag-Grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to create a custom drodpdown on column Header that have `UI elements as below (containing some input type text and buttons and unordered list)`and this dropdown should get list of column defs inside it as list.
Is there way to achieve this, to create custom dropdown div on column header in ag-Grid. How should I get a click event on column header when clicked?

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/

## Here is the plunker link:-

https://plnkr.co/edit/hztm3jf5FDBK2unX

## .jsx:-

```
<AgGridReact
  columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
  defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
  rowData={this.state.rowData}
  // frameworkComponents={this.state.frameworkComponents}
  onGridReady={this.onGridReady}            
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getMainMenuItems`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/#example-column-menu) callback to customize the column menu content. The example below demonstrates how you can add a list of user provided column settings in the `generalMenuTab`. You can also update the value of some of the column settings here using `GridApi.setColumnDefs()` and see the result immediately.

```js
getMainMenuItems = (params: GetMainMenuItemsParams) => {
  const { api, columnApi } = params;
  const menuItems = [] as MenuItemDef[];
  const colDef = params.column.getColDef();
  const userProvidedColDefKeys = Object.keys(colDef);

  userProvidedColDefKeys.forEach((key) => {
    const value = colDef[key];
    const menuItem: MenuItemDef = { name: key };
    const updateColDef = (key: string, value: any) => {
      const colDefs = api?.getColumnDefs();
      const newColDefs = colDefs?.map((c) => {
        const newColDef = {};

        Object.keys(c).forEach((key) => {
          if (userProvidedColDefKeys.includes(key)) {
            newColDef[key] = c[key];
          }
        });
        if (c.field === colDef.field) {
          newColDef[key] = value;
        }
        return newColDef;
      });
      api?.setColumnDefs(newColDefs);
    };

    if (typeof value === "boolean") {
      menuItem.subMenu = [
        {
          name: "Yes",
          checked: value,
          action: () => updateColDef(key, true)
        },
        {
          name: "No",
          checked: !value,
          action: () => updateColDef(key, false)
        }
      ];
    } else if (typeof value === "number") {
      if (key === "flex") {
        menuItem.subMenu = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((flex) => ({
          name: flex.toString(),
          checked: flex === value,
          action: () => updateColDef(key, flex)
        }));
      } else if (
        key === "width" ||
        key === "minWidth" ||
        key === "maxWidth"
      ) {
        menuItem.subMenu = [50, 100, 200, 300, 500].map((width) => ({
          name: width.toString(),
          checked: width === value,
          action: () => updateColDef(key, width)
        }));
      }
    }

    menuItems.push(menuItem);
  });

  return menuItems;
};
```

### Usage

```js
<AgGridReact
  getMainMenuItems={this.getMainMenuItems}
  {...}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64059440/adding-custom-drodpdown-on-column-header-in-ag-grid]

Comment: Thanks @NearHuscarl. As above UI contains an input type='text' as a part of dropdown. Can we add that as a part of UI and some checkbox same as columnsMenuTab as a part of dropdown.

Comment: No you can't unless you override the whole header component completely and write your own column menu from scratch. One workaround I can think of is to open a dialog with an input field to update the value when the user clicks the menu. @Mahi

Comment: ok. Can you help me in achieving the UI part and getting the corresponding column header columnDef and "gridApi" and "gridColumnApi" data inside that dropdown div.

Comment: @Mahi Can you elaborate more? The column menu in my answer can already display all of the `colDef` properties that you provide in the `gridOptions`. Or do you want to display **all** colDef properties (including the properties that you don't specify)?

Comment: I am looking for UI part containing input type and checkboxes and buttons on dropdown div on each column when toggled  through column header which have info about its own header columnDef where it is toggled.

Comment: is there any way to achieve that @NearHuscarl.